# I want to migrate Tables from one server to another server using IICS in a single shot ( Multiple Table migration at Same time), Any solution?

Tags: parallel-processing, migration, informatica, informatica-powercenter, iics

I want to migrate tables from one server to another server using Informatica Intelligent Cloud Services (IICS) in a single operation, with the ability to migrate multiple tables simultaneously. I have already managed to migrate tables, but it's currently happening sequentially. My goal is to perform this migration in parallel to speed up the process. Any solutions or suggestions

Comment: Create a taskflow to run your tasks in parallel?